# Google voices list doesn't contains French language from France

Tags: google-text-to-speech

Google voice API https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/voices doesn't have French voice.

fr-FR-Standard-A
fr-FR-Standard-C
fr-FR-Wavenet-A
fr-FR-Wavenet-C
fr-FR-Wavenet-D
fr-FR-Wavenet-E

Comment: Hello Mohamed! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are various French(France), French(Canadian) Male and Female voices while using Text-to-Speech in GCP.
You can see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices) that shows all the supported voices while using Text-to-Speech.

Additionally you can [create a Custom voice](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/custom-voice/docs) while training a model, but for this you need to contact a [member of the sales team](https://cloud.google.com/contact).